# Is there anything more efficient than an array of objects in javascript to store large amounts of data?

Tags: javascript

My application gathers acceleration 10 times a second, therefore I have a need to store thousands of rows of data. Currently I have an object which is a list of other objects to store it all - anything more efficient than that?

```
var arr = [];

function dataPoint(x, y, z, tstamp) {
    this.xAccel = x;
    this.yAccel = y;
    this.zAccel = z;
    this.epoch = tstamp;
}

var dp = new dataPoint( acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z, acceleration.timestamp );

arr.push(dp);
```

Comment: Please show your actual data structure and we can comment on that specifically.

Comment: It's not always just about how much data you put in, but also how you intend to read it/use it at runtime.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for?  A custom `SuperFastArray` implementation that does everything that the array does, except quicker?  If all you are using the arrays for is index-based access, there isn't anything faster than that.  Are you ever iterating through the array to find a specific item?  Because there are a lot of ways to optimize that.

Comment: No, just storing the data and only looping at the end to produce a CSV - but I am not concerned about that, only concerned about runtime performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the platform you're targeting supports [typed arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) then those would probably be more efficient.

- [Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/)
- [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays)

Comment: "Platform"?  Are we not talking about javascript?

Comment: @Kirk: If we're talking about the browser, then I'm referring to a browser. However, JavaScript doesn't always live in a browser, and the question did not specifically refer to a browser environment, so I chose a more generic term, *platform*.

Comment: Sure sure, the first link confused me into believing you were thinking this was language agnostic.  Apologies.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code:

```
> var arr = [];  
> function dataPoint(x, y, z, tstamp) {
>     this.xAccel = x;
>     this.yAccel = y;
>     this.zAccel = z;
>     this.epoch = tstamp;
> }
> var dp = new dataPoint( acceleration.x, acceleration.y,
>          acceleration.z, acceleration.timestamp );
> arr.push(dp);
```

I don't see why you're bothering with a constructor, you could simply do (abbreviated):

```
  arr.push({x: acc.x, y: acc.y, z: acc.z, epoch: acc.timestamp});
```

though I'd probably change `epoch` to `t`. And given that you have such as simple structure, why not:

```
  arr.push([acc.x, acc.y, acc.z, acc.timestamp]);
```

and reference the members by index. The advantage of a constructor is inherited methods, but if you only have one level of inheritance, simple functions are just a effective and probably faster to execute (lookups on the global object are generally very fast compared to `[[Prototype]]` chains, but see the caveat below)

Incidentally, I think the name *epoch* is being used in the wrong context. An epoch is a reference point, so you might have an epoch of say 2012-04-20T18:53:21.098Z and then have deltas from that in units like milliseconds or seconds. The epoch for javascript time references (i.e. the value returned by `Date.prototype.getTime`) is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, the time reference is a delta from that.

#### Caveat

In regard to what is "best", I presume your criterion is "fastest", with the caveat that the code must still be reasonably clear and maintainable. Your best bet there is to avoid obvious speed issues, then test in a wide variety of browsers and optimise based on results. An optimisation in one browser may have little or no difference in others, or may be significantly slower. e.g. decrementing loops used to be faster in most browsers, but much slower in Opera. Also, evaluating expressions in loop conditions, like:

```
  while ((el = node.firstChild))
```

were once much slower than:

```
  while (el) {
    el = node.firstChild
```

but it doesn't seem to matter as much with newer browsers. Similarly, for loops are just as fast (generally) as while and do loops. but take more typing to setup.

Comment: This did not work - creating the data structure on the fly fails.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the post then. There is no way that writing the data directly to an array and pushing it into another array is slower than calling a constructor, then pushing the resulting object into an array.

Comment: [Here's a jsperf exampe](http://jsperf.com/constructor-vs-array-literal) where the array method is faster than a constructor in most browsers (hugely in Firefox). Where it isn't faster (Opera 11, IE 6) it is neck and neck. Depends on your target audience I guess.